# How can you distinguish a "Standard" Card fro a "Modern" Card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I recently played in a Standard draft at Friday night magic and I was informed that there are certain specific sets of cards that can be used in Standard.

I am aware that Modern includes all standard cards also. what I want to know is how can you distinguish which cards you can use in standard?

Is there any symbolisation for a standard card? As the markers in the right hand side of the creature type line such as M14 and so on seem to not make much difference.

Comment: The answers on the possible duplicate should make this clear, but for emphasis, standard is a rotating format, with only some number of the most recent sets allowed, so there's no way for cards to be physically marked as standard legal. But the set marker (e.g. M14 as you said) does still determine whether a card is standard legal; you just need to know what sets are currently in standard.

Comment: Ah this duplicate did not appear in the related section... like at all

Comment: The markers on the right hand side are WHAT make the difference : p

Comment: The symbol doesn't tell you everything.  A 20+ year old [mtg:shatter] printed in alpha is currently legal in standard, as it's also a common in Khans of Tarkir (a set currently allowed in standard).

Comment: What *format* a card is in being printed on the card doesn't make much sense: cards in standard now won't be in standard two years from now (unless they're reprinted). You just have to *know* what sets are in standard at the moment.